# SonataAdminBundle: how to create a SonataBlock and save it to database?

Tags: sonata-admin, doctrine-phpcr

I try to create a new block from SonataBlockBundle, edit the content block and want to save it to database.

in my composer.json, i got:

```
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.3.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3.4",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "^2.3.0",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.3.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony-cmf/block-bundle": "^1.3.1",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.2.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "1.0.*"
```

In the dashboard, i got no menu to create a new block, and i got this error in the console:

```
The following document types provided in valid_children are invalid: Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\ContentBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\StaticContent The class names provided could not be loaded
```

Can i use the symfony-cmf/block-bundle as a standalone without install all the symfony-cmf ?

How to simply create a SonataBlock, and save it to database ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can mix in symfony-cmf/block-bundle with SonataAdminBundle.  But I can tell you, how to display Block's (SonataBlockBundle) on your dashboard.

1. Include the SonataBlockBundle described in [SonataBlockBundle's
   Installation
   Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/installation.html).
2. Refer to [SonataAdminBundle's Dashboard
   Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/dashboard.html)
   to configure blocks on your dashboard.

In short it's pretty easy to configure more blocks (or even custom ones, just register them):

```
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            -
                position: top
                type:     sonata.block.service.text
                settings:
                    content: >
                        <p>My dashboard block</p>
                        <p>Feel free to extend me</p>
```